# Can you send keyboard events to a react component with only it's ref?

Tags: reactjs, input, keyboard, keyboard-events, ref

Given an input defined as:

```
<input ref={myRef} onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
```

I want to have a button that can send a keyboard event to this input as if I typed the key in the input itself. The reason I don't want to just update the value is because there is some masking done (currency) on the input already, and I don't want to change any of that code if I don't need to.

I've seen online code that looks like this:

```
document.dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    keyCode: 69, // example values
    code: "KeyE" // put everything you need in this object
  })
);
```

I tried replacing document with `myRef` but that didn't work. So I'm wondering if this is even possible?

Edit:

I've also tried this without success:

```
myRef.current.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
  code: 'Digit8',
  key: 'Digit8',
  charKode: 56,
  keyCode: 56,
  view: window
}));
```

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-goodall-zjz90